Add a custom input file field to WooCommerce Checkout Based on Cart Total
I'm trying to add a custom field to the WooCommerce checkout page, but I want it to appear only when the order total exceeds a certain amount, let's say 500. I've looked into modifying the form-checkout.php template file in my theme, but I'm unsure of how to implement this conditional logic:
// Remove currency symbol and comma
$cart_total_numeric = floatval(str_replace(array(get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(), ','), '', $cart_total));

// Check if order total is greater than 500
if ($cart_total_numeric > 500) {
    echo '<div id="billing_uploadsign_field" class="billing-uploadsign-field">';

    woocommerce_form_field('billing_uploadsign', array(
        'type'     => 'file',
        'class'    => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'    => __('Upload Signature', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value('billing_uploadsign'));

    echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review'); ?>

However, the custom field is not showing up on the checkout page, regardless of the order total. I suspect there might be an issue with my implementation of the conditional logic.
Can someone provide guidance on how to properly add a custom field to the WooCommerce checkout page based on the order total?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As uploads doesn't work in WooCommerce checkout, you will need to use something like in this thread: How to add file upload to WooCommerce checkout?
As cart total may change in checkout page depending on chosen shipping method, you should use instead cart subtotal.
Also, you can use woocommerce_review_order_before_submit available hook, instead of overriding WooCommerce template file.
Once you have enabled checkout upload adding the custom plugin from this thread, you can conditionally display your file upload field with:
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'display_checkout_upload_signature_field' );
function display_checkout_upload_signature_field() {
    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal > 500 ) {
        echo '<div class="upload_file-wrapper">';

        // The select field
        woocommerce_form_field('upload_signature', array(
            'type'     => 'file',
            'class'    => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'    => __('Upload Signature', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
            'max_size' => '3072', // in ko (here 3 Mo size limit)
            'accept'   => 'image/*,.doc,.docx,.rtf,.txt',
        ), WC()->checkout->get_value('upload_signature'));

        echo '</div>';
    }
}

You will certainly need some more things explained on this thread like field validation (if the field is required), and more…
Notes about cart subtotal and total amounts:

Use WC()->cart->subtotal to get the cart subtotal including taxes,
Use WC()->cart->get_subtotal() to get the cart subtotal excluding taxes,
Use WC()->cart->get_total() to get the cart total including taxes,

